How to receive from /dev/udp using bash?
Using bash, how do you receive using /dev/udp?
Sending works. It seems weird but I can't make receive work (even though I think I did it in the past). So, I must be doing something very stupid.
From one session, I send periodic UDP packets:
$ while true; do echo foo >/dev/udp/localhost/5555; sleep 1; done

I see the packets using wireshark and netcat can receive them:
$ nc -ulW1 localhost 5555
foo
$ 

But redirecting input from /dev/udp/localhost/5555 receives nothing. All the following commands hang without reading anything.
$ cat </dev/udp/localhost/5555
$ read line </dev/udp/localhost/5555

Replacing localhost with 127.0.0.1 does not change anything. And you may have noticed that sending to /dev/udp/localhost/5555 works.
Please, do not answer "use netcat". I know netcat works. I want to understand what's wrong with redirecting input from /dev/udp.
FWIW, it's bash version 5.2.21 on Ubuntu 24.04 but it shouldn't matter anyway.

[so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

/dev/udp/... and /dev/tcp/... are only used to connect to the specified destination, not to bind to the given address and listen (tcp) and receive data (udp).

@SteffenUllrich do you have a reference for this statement?

@ThierryLelegard: strace -f bash -c 'cat </dev/udp/127.0.0.1/port' - and then you'll see the connect, not some kind of bind. And there is no other syntax defined which might be used for a bind

Looking through the bash source, it looks like tcp and udp socket redirections only work for connecting to a remote socket, not listening for incoming connections  (They connect to an address, don't bind to a local port and then accept)

If any port is occupied by an application then its hard to listen on the same port with different application, in a simple word you can't listen a single port with 2 different applications. But there is a way you can get the data which is getting transferred by that port, you can use this command ngrep -d any -W byline port 5555 to grep the data which that port is sending or receiving.

Using loadable accept module, you could listen for TCP connection, not for udp. Maybe you could edit accept loadable module.
